# Adding Hyphen between text in Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have list of numbers like this (S20170146) and I want to turn them to this format(S2017-01-46).Basically, I need to add "-" between the numbers.  I am using Arcmap I know how to use feild calculator. But I don't know to write python code to do this?

Comment: Are the segments of the string always the same length? S(4 digits)-(2 digits)-(2 digits)? If so, it would be pretty easy to write an expression to grab the right chunks and then concatenate them with dashes.

Comment: Yes. they are start with S. But I don't know how to write the expression to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing along with string formatting to accomplish this:

```
new_string = '{}-{}-{}'.format(old_string[:5], old_string[5:7], old_string[7:])
```

Explanation of the 3 slices:

1. The first 5 elements of the sequence (index 0-4)
2. 2 elements, index 5 & 6
3. All remaining elements (index 7-end)

[This page gives a decent explanation on slicing strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: can i run this in Field Calculator?

Comment: Yes. Be sure to select the Python interpreter option and replace `old_string` with the attribute name.

Comment: I post my Field Calculator setting.I cannot run your code and I get error.

Comment: Try removing those spaces between the attribute name and the [] brackets to be safe. You also need to actually calculate the value to new_string: replace thing(!LAST_allpaving_!) with new_string.

Comment: You don't need to use the codeblock. Just paste in everything to the right of the '=' from my expression, and make the changes @Alex suggests.

Comment: Just to be safe, you may want to create another text attribute for your output, instead of over-writing the existing data. When it is successful and to your desires, you can copy it back to the original field.

Answer (score 1):

pre-logic code block might work better as:

```
def thing(last_allpaving):
  return '{}-{}-{}'.format(last_allpaving[:5], last_allpaving[5:7], last_allpaving[7:])
```

as stated in some comments, it is not necessary to use a pre-logic code block, but if you choose to do so, this should help.

***In general***...

When using The Field Calculator with a Python expression, the '*expression*' part is said to be the value that you set your field equal to. This expression has to be something that Python can parse like a constant or a built-in pre-defined function like:

```
arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['SourceDir'][:40]
```

as shown here:

[image]

An ***Advanced*** Python Expression implies we want to run our own pre-processing function which is previously un-defined in order to arrive at the calculated value. For this, we need to check the *Show Codeblock* option box.

[image]

In the *Pre-Logic Script Code* text area, we can enter our user-defined python function

```
def my_new_function(field_data):
  x = field_data
  y = x[:8]
  z = y[5:]
  return z
```

and in the *Expression* text area, we are now able to call our new user-defined function using

```
my_new_function( !LOC_DATA! )
```

Care must be taken to ensure that the value returned by your user-defined function is a *type* that is compatible with the field that you are calcualting. (ie. I wouldn't recommend trying to put a *String* into an *Integer* field)